# I dont know what does it mean SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'else'

Tags: jquery

Could you check my code. I have an error in my if statement.
What is it mean with 
**SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'else'**

```
$ (document).ready(function($)
{
    var sum = 0;
    var numberQA = 4

    $('.skillA:checkbox').click(function()
    {
        sum = 0;

        $('.skillA:checkbox:checked').each(function(idx,elm)
        {
            // idx: index position of selector, elm = this selector,
            sum += parseInt(elm.value, 10);
        });

        // average = sum / numberQA;
        $('#totalSkillA').html(sum);

        if (4 <= sum <=6)
        {        
            $('#communicationSkill1').css({
                "backgroundColor":"#087cb7",
                "color":"white"
            });

        else if (7 <= sum <=10)
        {        
            $('#communicationSkill2').css({
                "backgroundColor":"#087cb7",
                "color":"white"
            });

        else if (11 <= sum <=13)
        {
            $('#communicationSkill3').css({
                "backgroundColor":"#087cb7",
                "color":"white"
            });    

        else if (14 <= sum <= 16)
        {        
            $('#communicationSkill4').css({
                "backgroundColor":"#087cb7",
                "color":"white"
            });
    }
});
```

Comment: You need to end your ”if” statement with ”else”, not ”if else”.

Comment: Still got the same error

Comment: No, you need to put your `else if` outside of your `if` block. In your case just remove the brackets of your `if`.

Comment: @Ivar It is already outside of if block. Check the code.

Comment: @m.alban Your're right. More or less. The brackets don't make sense in this code. The `if` has an opening bracket but not a closing one. Same counts for the `else if`s. But there is no reason it should end with an `else` instead of `if else`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should train more in programming.

1. `4<=sum<=6` is wrong. change it to `4 <= sum && sum <= 6` (Read [JavaScript Operators](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp))
2. You must close if and else if block: (Read [JavaScript if else and else if](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp))

   ```
   if ( /* condition*/ )
   {
       // statements
   }
   else if ( /* condition*/ )
   {
       // statements
   }
   else
   {
       // statements
   }
   ```

Comment: wow it works. Thank you very much. There is an error that, when sum=14 or 15 or 16 all the statement in other else if are true

Comment: @AndyLe You can set this answer as accepted answer then others can use it. good luck

Comment: Do you know how to fix the statement. Like when sum=16 all the ID are set up with the css. Something wrong

Comment: @AndyLe Maybe it's better to google your problem or ask another question for your new problem. good luck

Comment: I have to wait 7 days :( I need to make my code done today

Comment: @AndyLe It depends on your new edition of code (after solving syntax error). so without viewing your code, I can't help you.

Comment: Can I have your email

Comment: @AndyLe m.a.taghvazadeh@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Think you need something like this

```
if (4 <= sum <= 6) {
    $('#communicationSkill1').css({"backgroundColor": "#087cb7", "color": "white"})
}
else if (7 <= sum <= 10) {
    $('#communicationSkill2').css({"backgroundColor": "#087cb7", "color": "white"})
}
else if (11 <= sum <= 13) {
    $('#communicationSkill3').css({"backgroundColor": "#087cb7", "color": "white"})
}
else if (14 <= sum <= 16) {
    $('#communicationSkill4').css({"backgroundColor": "#087cb7", "color": "white"})
} else 
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: @AndyLe you are welcome, I suggest you to train more about operators also. You can use codecademy or w3.

Comment: Do you know how to fix the statement. Like when sum=16 all the ID are set up with the css. Something wrong